# Rails in linux. Is the server running on host “localhost” (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, postgresql

Disclamer: I went through identical titles and none helped me solve my problem.

I installed and started a postgresql server:
I first delete `pgdata/postmaster.pid` to make sure is not the same problem as other posts.
then
`pg_ctl start`
`lsof | grep 5432` -> nothing

`pg_ctl start`  -> *...listening on Unix socket "sockets/.s.PGSQL.5432"...database system is ready to accept connections...*
`lsof | grep 5432` -> *postgres   1495          username    4u     unix 0x0000000000000000       0t0   16163716 sockets/.s.PGSQL.5432 type=STREAM*

then I go for: `rake db:setup` and I get:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
Couldn't create 'seqresults-test' database. Please check your configuration.
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Then I can access the database with the client.

```
$ psql
```

then

```
postgres=#
```

Help please! All this looks like black magic to me and it's not working.
I will also appreciate if someone could briefly explain how does this work.

Comment: Can you try this approach? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65427026/converting-django-from-sqlite-to-postgresql/65428511#65428511

Comment: @Danizavtz. Thank you. I don't have sudo power. What is the alternative?

Comment: Have you tried docker?

Comment: @Danizavtz. No and I don't know how.

Comment: Is hosted services an alternative to you? aws or google gcp. If you have a instance in heroku you can have a database for free until 10K lines. There is also 500Mb free from atlas (mongodb). If none, Maybe you can use sqlite (local file system). There is a postgresql hosted service called elephantsql (I never used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your postgres is listening on a unix socket (a special kind of file), not a tcp one.

You can try connecting via that socket (location on your system will probably be different, you need the directory where `.s.PGSQL.5432` file is located):

```yaml
# database.yml
  host: '/var/run/postgresql'
  database: ...
```

Comment: How can I make Postgres listen on a tcp socket?